# Is there a way to show app icons in Mission Control?

Tags: macos, mission-control, preferences

When I used Mission Control, I like to show all my open apps (not in groups) , but when I have a lot of windows, it would be nice to have an overlay of the application icon over the image of the window (similar to the icon beneath the windows when grouping is turned on). Is there some hidden preference / terminal command / utility that can facilitate this? Thank you!

Comment: No, app icons only show for groups.

Answer (score 2):

System Preferences>mission control>group windows by application[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such option.